# How to redirect output of wget as input to unzip?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

I have to download a file from this [link](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.phpsrc_id=11834). The file download is a zip file which I will have to unzip in the current folder.

Normally, I would download it first, then run the unzip command.

```
wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 -O temp.zip
unzip temp.zip
```

But in this way, I need to execute two commands, wait for the completion of first one to execute the next one, also, I must know the name of the file `temp.zip` to give it to `unzip`.

Is it possible to redirect output of `wget` to `unzip`? Something like

```
unzip < `wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834`
```

But it didn't work.

```
bash: `wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 -O temp.zip`: ambiguous redirect
```

Also, `wget` got executed twice, and downloaded the file twice.

Comment: In the latter example, wget probably was executed twice because the ? is a special character in the shell. Putting the URL in ""s should help.

Comment: This thread seems to have a solution. Haven't tried it myself though. http://serverfault.com/questions/26474/unzipping-files-that-are-flying-in-through-a-pipe

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You have to download your files to a temp file, because (quoting the unzip man page):

> Archives  read  from  standard input
>   are not yet supported, except with
>   funzip  (and  then only  the  first 
>   member  of  the  archive  can  be
>   extracted).

Just bring the commands together:

```
wget "http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834" -O temp.zip
unzip temp.zip
rm temp.zip
```

But in order to make it more flexible you should probably put it into a script so you save some typing and in order to make sure you don't accidentally overwrite something you could use the `mktemp` command to create a safe filename for your temp file:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
PWD=`pwd`
wget "$1" -O $TMPFILE
unzip -d $PWD $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

Comment: Is ```wget file.zip && unzip file.zip``` the same as ```wget file.zip; unzip file.zip``` or is one preferred over the other? Thanks :)

Comment: @NextLocal `wget && unzip` will run unzip only if wget succeeded. `wget ; unzip` will run unzip anyway, possibly pointing to non existent file.

Comment: funzip was the answer I was looking for. Terraform (for some reason) packages it's binary as a single file in a zip archive so this was perfect for me.

Answer (score 120):

This is a repost of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132514/bash-how-to-unzip-a-piped-zip-file-from-wget-qo/) to a similar question:

The ZIP file format includes a directory (index) at the end of the archive. This directory says where, within the archive each file is located and thus allows for quick, random access, without reading the entire archive.

This would appear to pose a problem when attempting to read a ZIP archive through a pipe, in that the index is not accessed until the very end and so individual members cannot be correctly extracted until after the file has been entirely read and is no longer available. As such it appears unsurprising that most ZIP decompressors simply fail when the archive is supplied through a pipe.

The directory at the end of the archive is not the *only* location where file meta information is stored in the archive. In addition, individual entries also include this information in a local file header, for redundancy purposes.

Although not every ZIP decompressor will use local file headers when the index is unavailable, the tar and cpio front ends to libarchive (a.k.a. bsdtar and bsdcpio) *can and will* do so when reading through a pipe, meaning that the following is possible:

```
wget -qO- http://example.org/file.zip | bsdtar -xvf-
```

Comment: This is excellent! I would note that tar gives me some warnings about the uncompressed data being the wrong size (expected 0), but the files themselves appear to be undamaged. Guessing this is due to the lack of the index.

Comment: I have a `.zip`-file here that contains files with executable permissions. When I download and pipe into `bsdtar`, the exec bits get thrown away. When I download to disk and extract with `bsdtar` or `unzip` then, the exec bits are honoured.

Comment: // , @GolarRamblar, didst ever find out why?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: [here](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1106#issuecomment-446219915) is the answer. In short: A ZIP archive has two places where it stores such information, that can be inconsistent, and depending if the file `bsdtar` opens is seekable or not it uses the one or the other place.

Answer (score 33):

If you have the JDK installed, you can use `jar`:

```
wget -qO- http://example.org/file.zip | jar xvf /dev/stdin
```

Comment: I just found that `jar` doesn't preserve file permissions. Nice trick otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to give a file param, just use `| jar xv`

Comment: I, too, was bitten by the assumption than `jar` could be used as a replacement for `unzip`; Unfortunately `jar` does not restore extracted files' permissions;

Comment: Just use `| jar x`

Comment: `jar` is much nicer handling UTF-8 filenames. `unzip` mangled things.

Comment: Does the pkzip format even store file permissions in the first place?

Answer (score 26):

Repost of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759718/9645167):

BusyBox's `unzip` can take stdin and extract all the files.

```
wget -qO- http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip | busybox unzip -
```

The dash after `unzip` is to use stdin as input.

You can even,

```
cat file.zip | busybox unzip -
```

But that's just redundant of `unzip file.zip`.

If your distro uses BusyBox by default (e.g. Alpine), just run `unzip -`.

Comment: further to @Saftever's answer, which i'm not allowed to comment on, busybox will work but versions older than 1.27.0 won't due to a redundant lseek, see changelog https://busybox.net/

Answer (score 20):

I don't think you even want to bother piping wget's output into unzip.

From the wikipedia ["ZIP (file format)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) article:

> A ZIP file is identified by the presence of a central directory located at the end of the file.

wget has to completely finish the download before unzip can do any work, so they run sequentially, not interwoven as one might think.

Answer (score 18):

The proper syntax would be:

```
$ unzip <(curl -sL https://www.winpcap.org/archive/1.0-docs.zip)
```

but it won't work, because of the error (*Info-ZIP* on *Debian*):

```
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)

Archive:  /dev/fd/63
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /dev/fd/63 or
        /dev/fd/63.zip, and cannot find /dev/fd/63.ZIP, period.
```

or on BSD/OS X:

```
Trying to read large file (> 2 GiB) without large file support
```

This is, because the standard zip tools are mainly using [`lseek` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Position-Primitive.html) in order to set the file offset at the end to read its *end of central directory record*. It is located at the end of the archive structure and it is required to read the list of the files (see: [Zip file format structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure)). Therefore the file cannot be FIFO, pipe, terminal device or any other dynamic, because the input object cannot be positioned by the `lseek` function.

So you have the following workarounds:

- use different kind of compression (e.g. `tar.gz`),
- you have to use two separate commands,
- use alternative tools (as suggested in other answers),
- create an alias or function to use multiple commands.

Comment: I think it still *could* be a FIFO. You'd just have to keep reading from the FIFO until EOF (effectively buffering the whole FIFO in memory or in a temp file). Totally doable to ease script creation, but not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one file in zip, you can use `zcat` or `gunzip` or `funzip` :

```
wget -qO- http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 | funzip -
```

To unzip more that one file inside a zip archive provided from a pipe, you can either [wait for the unzip team to implement it](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/UnZip.html#Future) or use the `busybox unzip` [solution from Saftever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759718/5649639).

Just for information : Here are the definitions of `gunzip` and `zcat` on my system :

```
$ grep ^exec $(which gunzip zcat)
/bin/gunzip:exec gzip -d "$@"
/bin/zcat:exec gzip -cd "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me quite well on macOS :

```bsh
tar xvf <(curl -sL http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834)

jar xvf <(curl -sL http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834)

wget -qO- http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 | tar xvf -

wget -qO- http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 | jar xvf -
```

BTW : The `tar` version used here is :

```
$ tar --version
bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6
```

Comment: The `tar` tool on my system says: `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`. I use `tar (GNU tar) 1.30` on ubuntu/debian. Can you please add the `tar --version` output of the `tar` tool you have used your system to type these commands in your answer ?

Comment: @SebMa I'm using latest macOS and all these commands works for me. My `tar --version` command output is: bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6

Comment: @SebMa
Output for both (1st and 3rd line of code) is same for me:
x doc/NERD_tree.txt
x nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
x nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
x plugin/NERD_tree.vim

Comment: You are using `bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6` on macOS. On Linux, we have `GNU tar` which has a bit different behavior.

Comment: well, but anyway, it's not a reason to delete my answer) It worked on latest macOS environment what I'm also mentioned

Comment: I did add a little precision on your answer thanks to your comments but I am NOT the one to have deleted your answer because I find it useful, I even installed the `libarchive-tools` ubuntu package (containing the `bsdtar`) for that matter. I am also the first one to have up-voted your answer. I swear G-D I did NOT delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `zip` archive is not sequential because it often has the table of contents at the end of the file, so it is difficult to stream-unzip it.

An alternative solution is to see if you can get another file format, like `.tar.gz`.

For example, if you're downloading a `.zip` file from GitHub, there is almost always a `.tar.gz` version available.

For example,

- https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.11.zip
- https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.11.tar.gz
- https://github.com/curl/curl/archive/curl-7_68_0.zip
- https://github.com/curl/curl/archive/curl-7_68_0.tar.gz

Notice the pattern -- just replace `.zip` with `.tar.gz` and pipe to `| tar xzf -`