# Listing files from nested zip files without extracting

Tags: shell-script, zip

I have a set of nested zip files and I need to list the file names **without extracting** the archives. For example:

- Zip1.zip

  - text1
  - text2
  - Zip2.zip

    - Sample1
    - Sample2

with some shell scripting should result in a list such as

```
Zip1.zip
Zip1.zip/text1
Zip1.zip/text2
Zip1.zip/Zip2.zip/Sample1
Zip1.zip/Zip2.zip/Sample2
```

Comment: how do you expect anything to be able to list the contents of zip2 without extracting it?

Comment: Using python following is implemented. i need it in shellscript    [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930515/unzip-nested-zip-files-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The unzip -p flag will pipe the uncompressed data to stdout. Unfortunately the `unzip` program doesn't have an option to read from stdin for some reason. Adapting the python one liner from [this](https://serverfault.com/a/280816) answer to a similar question does the trick.

eg:

```
unzip -p Zip1.zip Zip1/zip2.zip| python -c 'import zipfile,sys,StringIO;print "\n".join(zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())).namelist())'
```

Added: The Java jar tool can read from stdin. stolen from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229051/17864) answer.

eg:

```
unzip -p Zip1.zip  Zip1/zip2.zip| jar -t
```

output:

```
zip2/
zip2/Sample2
zip2/Sample1
```

original zip file:

```
$ unzip -l Zip1.zip 
Archive:  Zip1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2015-11-03 15:49   Zip1/
        5  2015-11-03 15:49   Zip1/text1
        5  2015-11-03 15:49   Zip1/text2
      474  2015-11-03 15:48   Zip1/zip2.zip
---------                     -------
      484                     4 files
```

Found the relevant Serverfault thread from [your](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/141021/sathish-r) - [comment](https://serverfault.com/a/280816).

---

This isn't a shell script, but it does what was suggested in the original question:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# Usage: python list-zips.py <zipfile>

import zipfile
import io
import sys

def uz(f, parent=[]):

    result = []
    try:
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
        for e in zf.namelist():
            path=parent+[e]
            if e.lower().endswith(".zip"):
                result += uz(io.BytesIO(zf.open(e).read()), path)
            else:
                result.append("/".join(path))

    except Exception as ex:
        return result

    return result

print("\n".join(uz(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"), [sys.argv[1]])))
```

```bsh
$ python list-zips.py Zip1.zip 
Zip1.zip/text1
Zip1.zip/text2
Zip1.zip/Zip2.zip/Sample1
Zip1.zip/Zip2.zip/Sample2
```

Comment: This does not work for nested zip archives or arbitrary nesting depth

Comment: Ok, well I added some follow up. I think this might help some folks, as it can be tricky working with archives without writing to disk.