# curl to stdout and untar a zip to a specific directory

Tags: directory, tar, curl, stdout

What is the correct way to curl to stdout, then `untar` (a zip file in that case) to a specific directory?

This failed:

```
curl URL | tar -x > /path
```

So I thought of this which also failed:

```
curl URL | tar -x > /path
```

Comment: Why would you untar a zip file rather than unzipping it?  Or is it a gzip file containing a tar archive?  gzip and zip are two different things.

Comment: `curl URL | unzip > /path` fails.

Comment: `unzip` _cannot_ unzip from standard input, as stated in its manual page.  You will have to write to a temporary file, `unzip` it, and delete the file.

Comment: That's why I contemplated `tar`... It's not possible at all with `tar`? I really don't know.

Comment: `tar` doesn't speak PKZip.

Comment: Oh, crap... Do you know a good fast alternative than? Please share a way if you know one. The ultimate goal is to download, extract, and redirect all in one line, shortest as possible.

Comment: Re. the above duplicate ([How to redirect output of wget as input to unzip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2690/86440)), see in particular the `jar` trick. As long as you don’t need to preserve permissions, it should work for you: it can extract from standard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to redirect output of wget as input to unzip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/how-to-redirect-output-of-wget-as-input-to-unzip) (`wget` and `curl` are interchangeable in this context). Please see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2691/41858) answer. Replicating it here:

```
wget URL -O path/temp.zip; unzip -d path path/temp.zip; rm path/temp.zip
```

Replace `URL` and `path` accordingly.