# Extract all content from multiple zip files contained in compressed tar archive

Tags: bash, shell, tar, zip

I receive a `tar.gz` file which packages multiple `zip` files - reproduced below:

```bash
$ rm -Rf zipdir; mkdir zipdir; echo foo > zipdir/a.txt; echo bar > zipdir/b.txt; cd zipdir; zip -m a.zip a.txt ; zip -m b.zip b.txt; cd ..; tar -czvf zipdir.tar.gz zipdir

$ tar tzfO zipdir.tar.gz
zipdir/
zipdir/a.zip
zipdir/b.zip

$ tar xzfO zipdir.tar.gz --no-anchored a.zip | gunzip -c
foo
$ tar xzfO zipdir.tar.gz --no-anchored b.zip | gunzip -c
bar
```

Extracting with `gunzip` (or `zcat -r`) for some reason stops at the first file. Subsequent files are not processed:

```
$ tar xzfO zipdir.tar.gz | gunzip -c
foo
```

How to concatenate contents of *all* zip files piped from STDOUT?

```
$ tar xzfO zipdir.tar.gz | ?
foo
bar
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `tar`:

```
$ zcat zipdir.tar.gz | tar x --to-command='zcat $TAR_FILENAME'
bar
foo
```

This won't unpack the original `tar.gz` and extract the contents of each zip file to stdout.
(My order in the tar is the other way around, hence `bar` before `foo`.)